# All check boxes selected for just one selection

Tags: python-2.7

I have a two check boxes in a gui. If i select one check box the other is automatically selected(and same with the deselection).

```
       C1 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(self, text = "GM1", variable = CheckVar1, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        C1.grid(column=0,row=0)
#        CheckBx1.pack()
        C2 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(self, text = "GM2", variable = CheckVar2, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        C2.grid(column=1,row=0)
#        CheckBx2.pack()
```

I am just doing this simple thing. Why are they not independent

I have another question to add here

```
def process(self):
    str(import_text_file)
    file = open(import_text_file,'r')
    print file.read()


def OnButtonClick(self):
    import_text_file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")])
    self.entry.insert(0, import_text_file)
```

and have declared `import_text_file = tk.StringVar`

But there is an error saying 'tkinter.stringVar' is not a valid file location.

Please help

Comment: Hello Can please someone answer the question

Comment: No one willing to respond